# How to horizontally centre a div without knowing its width?

Tags: css, html, screen-size

Here's the full screen result: http://jsfiddle.net/anik786/UYkSf/4/embedded/result/

Here's the HTML/CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/anik786/UYkSf/4/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="gallery_container">
<div class="pic">
    <img src="http://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2012/02/sample1_mini.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://www.ndaccess.com/Sample/Images/Image1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pic">
    <img src="http://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2012/02/sample1_mini.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://www.ndaccess.com/Sample/Images/Image1.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pic">
    <img src="http://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2012/02/sample1_mini.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="pic">
  <img src="http://www.ndaccess.com/Sample/Images/Image1.jpg" />
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {background: black;font-family: arial;}
.gallery_container{
 /* Insert styles here to make container center on page */
}
.pic {
 height: 300px;
width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px;
border: 10px solid white;
float: left;
}

.pic img{ 
height: 300px;
width: 300px; 
}
```

The problem is  that when the window size is at certain widths, there is too much space on the right hand side (try it out yourself with the full screen result by resizing the browser).

Therefore I'm trying to centre the container so that the gallery is always in the middle of the screen. I normally use:

**margin: 0 auto;**

However I can't use this because I don't know what the width of the container will be (as it depends on the window size).

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to centre elements:

Margin way:

With a set width or display: inline-block; you can use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

text-align way:

You can add this to the parent:

```
text-align: center;
```

Absolute way:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: width/2;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

The best way for you would be to remove the float on `.pic` and instead add `display: inline-block`. Then on the parent add `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` to center an item that has not been defined a given width. Then use `margin: 0 auto;`

Example http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/11/

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also center using max-width

```
max-width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

I assume the gallery would have a % width anyway in a responsive site.